# A complex SQL select based on multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
id        item_id         attribute           quantity
1         1               a                   2
2         1               b                   3
3         1               c                   4
4         2               a                   3
5         2               b                   3
6         3               a                   2
7         3               b                   1
```

I want to get all the different item_id's that have an attribute "a" with quantity more than 1 and at the same time attribute "b" with quantity more than 2.

if i put

```
select item_id
from table_name
where (attribute = a and quantity > 1) and (attribute = b and quantity >2)
```

i get no results...

How do i accomplish this? Please someone help fast it's for a paper I have due next week.

Comment: lol^^ do you have paypal?

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: @john conde - i did write my code and i did say it's not working and was asking for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Change your where clause to:

```
WHERE (attribute = a and quantity > 1) OR (attribute = b and quantity >2)
```

And your select to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_id
```

Comment: sorry mate, that would just return all the results based on whether any of the conditions is met at any time. i want both the conditions to apply.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   select item_id
   from Table1
   where (attribute = 'a' and quantity > 1) or (attribute = 'b' and quantity >2)
   group by item_id
```

[**SQL DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d7cf/8)

Comment: having and?  Maybe you want to edit this.

Comment: as i said to the other person that suggested an OR clause, it wouldnt work. if you see the edit I did on the question i managed to find a similar question with a solution. thanks though for the answer!

Comment: have you tried my query? it will give diferent user_id , as it shows in the demo , or what u want exactly? let me know

Comment: i dont want item id 3 to be in the results because it doesnt have an attribute b with quantity more than 2.

Comment: but id 3 have atribute a with quantity more then 1 !!

Comment: u want both ? id must have a and b , a with quantity more then 1 and b with quantity more then 2?

Comment: yes. and as I said i found an answer to that.

Comment: ok good that u found the answer . good luck

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: SOLVED!
After an hour of searching through SO i found this question, and its basically the same as mine and there is an answer that works (the first one).

[SQL - Select Query for complex dynamic rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376514/sql-select-query-for-complex-dynamic-rows)

Basically what the guy did is join the table to itself as many times as needed adding the next condition as a condition of the subsequent joins' tables named differently.

Comment: That'd just decrease your query's performance. Maybe you'd like to show us the resultant query and/or the resultset you desire?

Comment: as the guy said in the link i provided, lets say the attributes are products and the quantity is how many its sold, and the item id is a day parameter. i wanted to get a list of days when some items sold more than a specific number of times. i hope this makes it clearer?